# set alignment of a pane in a stack pane

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I try to create an application that contains 2 panes in a stackpane.
One pane is the main pane and is centered, the second is smaller and docked to the bottom-left of the stage.

The thing is that I've tried using 'setAlignment' and it does'nt seems to work (although the button is aligned). **The small pane is always centered.**

What is the problem and how I fix this?
I guess that maybe I can't align a pane, so how can I overcome this?

```
Pane pane = new Pane();

for (SerialPoint sp : points) {
    Circle circle = new Circle(sp.getX(), sp.getY(), 6, Color.GREEN);
    pane.getChildren().add(circle);
}

Pane smallPane = new Pane();
smallPane.setScaleX(0.25);
smallPane.setScaleY(0.25);
smallPane.setStyle("-fx-border-color: black;");

for (SerialPoint sp : points) {
    Circle circle = new Circle(sp.getX(), sp.getY(), 6, Color.RED);
    smallPane.getChildren().add(circle);
}

Button startBtn = new Button("Start");

StackPane stackPane = new StackPane(pane, smallPane, startBtn);
StackPane.setAlignment(smallPane, Pos.BOTTOM_LEFT);
StackPane.setAlignment(startBtn, Pos.TOP_RIGHT);
StackPane.setMargin(startBtn, new Insets(5));

Scene scene = new Scene(stackPane);
```

(SerialPoint is my inner class)

This is what I get: [image]

Comment: Don't use `StackPane`. Use `BorderPane` or `VBoxes` and `HBoxes`.

Comment: [`AnchorPane`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/AnchorPane.html) can probably suit your needs too.

Comment: If your `Scene` layout is static, I suggest you use [SceneBuilder](http://gluonhq.com/products/scene-builder/).

Comment: I think what is happening is that the pane is simply filling the entire stack pane, before scaling. Transformations are applied after layout, so the small pane fills the entire stack pane, and then is scaled 25% with the scaling being applied around its center. Consequently the scaled pane appears centered. Try wrapping the small pane in a `Group`, adding the group to the stack pane instead of adding the small pane directly, and setting the alignment on the group. (If you post an actual [MCVE] that we can test, I can make this precise in an answer.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Place the scaled Pane inside a Group.  For layout purposes, StackPane (and other layout panes) will ignore scale factors and other transforms on nodes, but a Group will not.

From the [Group javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/scene/Group.html):

> Any transform, effect, or state applied to a Group will be applied to all children of that group. Such transforms and effects will NOT be included in this Group's layout bounds, however if transforms and effects are set directly on children of this Group, those will be included in this Group's layout bounds.

---

*Sample App*

[image: sample]

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.*;
import javafx.scene.*;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.util.Random;

public class AligningPains extends Application {

    private static final int N_POINTS = 5;
    private static final int MAX_POINT_POS = 100;
    private static final int POINT_RADIUS = 6;
    private static final int PREF_PANE_SIZE = 300;
    private static final int BUTTON_INSETS = 5;

    Point2D[] points = new Point2D[N_POINTS];
    Random random = new Random(42);

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        initPoints();

        Pane pane = new Pane();
        pane.setPrefSize(PREF_PANE_SIZE, PREF_PANE_SIZE);

        addCircles(pane, Color.GREEN);

        Pane smallPane = new Pane();
        smallPane.setStyle("-fx-border-color: black;");
        smallPane.setPrefSize(PREF_PANE_SIZE, PREF_PANE_SIZE);
        smallPane.setScaleX(0.25);
        smallPane.setScaleY(0.25);

        addCircles(smallPane, Color.RED);

        Group smallGroup = new Group(smallPane);

        Button startBtn = new Button("Start");

        StackPane stackPane = new StackPane(pane, smallGroup, startBtn);
        StackPane.setAlignment(smallGroup, Pos.BOTTOM_LEFT);
        StackPane.setAlignment(startBtn, Pos.TOP_RIGHT);
        StackPane.setMargin(startBtn, new Insets(BUTTON_INSETS));
        stackPane.setPrefSize(PREF_PANE_SIZE, PREF_PANE_SIZE);

        Scene scene = new Scene(stackPane);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    private void addCircles(Pane pane, Color color) {
        for (Point2D sp : points) {
            Circle circle = new Circle(sp.getX(), sp.getY(), POINT_RADIUS, color);
            pane.getChildren().add(circle);
        }
    }

    private void initPoints() {
        for (int i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
            points[i] = new Point2D(random.nextInt(MAX_POINT_POS), random.nextInt(MAX_POINT_POS));
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```